# Unity IOS firebase handle foreground push notification

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been using firebase unity(beta) plugin for push notification. I can get push notification data when my app is opened from notification screen with this method.

```
public void OnMessageReceived(object sender, Firebase.Messaging.MessageReceivedEventArgs e) {
            Debug.Log("Received a new message");
    }
```

But I can't get push notification data when my app is in foreground. 
How can I get this data? 
Anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

This solution solved my problem.

```
public void OnTokenReceived(object sender, Firebase.Messaging.TokenReceivedEventArgs token) {

    NotificationServices.GetRemoteNotification (NotificationServices.remoteNotificationCount-1);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but if anyone else comes across this, I was receiving messages all of the time on Android but on iOS, OnMessageReceived would not fire until I added content_available: true to the firebase notification payload.

Now, all is good and I can trigger actions in my foreground app through arbitrary data.